# FindNext - Returning Multiple Matches (With a little modification)

Tags: vba, excel

Great to be a part of this forum. Okay, so my problem statement goes like this:

I have 2 Excel files:
One is a master file which has a list of all unique servers, and another is a database file, which has applications mapped to these servers. Please note that in the database file, the server entries are not unique (as the same server can host more than one application).

The problem is that I have to now "find" where each server in the master file is located in the "database" file, and return the corresponding name of the application. Since there can be multiple applications on a server, I would like to return all the names of the applications in the same row (in adjacent columns).

Example:
If the name of the server is ServerA in the master, and there are 3 apps (A,B and C) which are mapped to this in the second file, my master file should now look like this after the script:

Server A   :    A   B   C

My code only seems to return up to two matches. It doesn't go beyond that, and I have thought about this for quite some time now, and searched all over the forum. Is there anything wrong in the logic used? Please help!

Here is the code I used:

```
    Dim FindWord As String, Loc As Range
    Dim aCell As Range

    Dim database As Worksheet
    Dim mastersheet As Worksheet
    Set database = Workbooks("DataBase09052017.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set mastersheet = Workbooks("EAS Apps Migration - Master Data Sheet_v2.0.xlsm").Worksheets("EAS Applications")

    Dim x, y As Integer
    x = 2
    y = 17

    Dim a, b, ctr, c As Integer
    a = 2
    b = 23
    c = 17

    Do Until x = 885
        y = 17
        FindWord = database.Cells(x, y).Value      
        Set Loc = mastersheet.Range("W2 : W6344").Find(What:=FindWord)

        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            database.Cells(x, y + 1).Value = mastersheet.Cells(Loc.Row, 1).Value
            Set aCell = Loc
            Do
                Set aCell = mastersheet.Range("W2: W6344").FindNext(aCell)
                y = y + 1
                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    database.Cells(x, y + 1).Value = mastersheet.Cells(aCell.Row, 1).Value
                End If
            Loop While aCell <> Loc
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: You **must** declare a type for **every** variable. This `Dim a, b, ctr, c As Integer` only declares `c` as `Integer` all the others are of type `Variant`! Also never use `Integer` (unless communication with old 16bit API) instead use `Long`: Using `Dim a As Long, b As Long, ctr As Long, c As Long` is the shortest way to declare **all** variables as `Long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this? I think your loop comparison was off (comparing Loc and aCell), and you might want to specify some Find parameters other than 'What'.

```
Sub x()

Dim FindWord As String, Loc As Range
Dim aCell As String

Dim database As Worksheet
Dim mastersheet As Worksheet
Set database = Workbooks("DataBase09052017.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set mastersheet = Workbooks("EAS Apps Migration - Master Data Sheet_v2.0.xlsm").Worksheets("EAS Applications")

Dim x As Long, y As Long
x = 2
y = 17

Dim a As Long, b As Long, ctr As Long, c As Long
a = 2
b = 23
c = 17

Do Until x = 885
    y = 17
    FindWord = database.Cells(x, y).Value
    Set Loc = mastersheet.Range("W2:W6344").Find(What:=FindWord)
    If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
        aCell = Loc.Address
        Do
            database.Cells(x, y + 1).Value = mastersheet.Cells(Loc.Row, 1).Value
            Set Loc = mastersheet.Range("W2:W6344").FindNext(Loc)
            y = y + 1
        Loop While aCell <> Loc.Address
    End If
    x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your inputs, but it doesn't seem to work. First, it returned an object error - probably because we were trying to set a range (aCell) to an address? (Loc.Address)? After that was corrected, I get an "Application or Object Defined error". Can you also explain the loop condition please? Shouldn't it be aCell.address<>Loc.Address?

Comment: I redefined aCell as a string to store the location of the first match. The loop continues while the cell being found has a different address (ie hasn't returned to the first match). (You don't want to compare the value of the range.) Can you tell me which line errors? Oops sorry - just spotted an error in the FindNext line which I have corrected.

Comment: Amazing, works just fine :). Thank you so much! Just for my understanding - where I went wrong earlier was in comparing the two "ranges"? Would the code work if we compare the two addresses instead - which is aCell.address<>Loc.address? I'd like to understand what exactly you've done :)

Comment: If you don't specify a property of a range variable the default is value so the loop was checking the value of each found cell against the value of the first match. In theory these would always match because you are searching for the same item each time (FindWord) which means the loop would never end. I mentioned the other parameters because they determine whether you are matching the whole cell or part of it (among other things). The fact that your loop did terminate suggests that it was looking for a partial match. Yes, you could have checked the two addresses. Does any of that make sense?!

Comment: That's interesting. So if I compare a "range" with a "range", it compares the value that is associated with it (which is the search string), is it? I didn't no that. I thought it compares the range address. This makes perfect sense. Thank you SJR!